# When did my remote desktop session on Windows started?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm working from home and I sometimes forget to "punch in". A few hours down the road I'm wondering when I started work and I want to find out when my remote desktop connection has been established.

How to find that out on a Windows 10 machine?

Note: I cannot use user login times, as my user is always logged in and the desktop is merely in the locked state when I start my remote desktop session.

Answer (score 1):

Since your userid is always logged on to the remote device, use Event Viewer on your device.  Open Event Viewer, expand Applications and Services , Microsoft, Windows, then Remote Desktop Connection, Session Services and see if that gives you your start times.

Edited to note "just" device to allow the device that gives the Event Viewer status

Comment: This log is unfortunately empty - do I have to enable something beforehand?,But your reply pointed me into the right direction. I can use the event viewer for `TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational` on my remote machine, which showed me the start time. (therefore: Upvoted but not marked as the accepted answer)

Comment: That serves as your answer then, because now you have your start time which is what you need.  And by the way, in my first post by "local machine" I meant the machine where you see the event giving you the time

Comment: @D.R. You can answer your own question if you wish, or John can modify their answer with the solution.